# How to remove app's sync account in Android instrumentation test

Tags: android, bdd, android-espresso, android-uiautomator

The app I am testing creates "sync account" (CMIIW, I might be wrong about the name) that can be seen in "Accounts" section in Android system settings. Unfortunately the account is **kept exist** so user doesn't need to re-authenticate **even after the app is re-installed**.

I need the app to start from **clean state** (i.e. like a brand new installed app, not logged in, etc) for each test runs. So that sync account removal (if any) is desired.

I am using Espresso and UiAutomator to run the instrumentation test. How to achieve this?

Any alternative approaches welcome!

Comment: Have you been able to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can execute adb command below before each test run to clear the app data. Not sure if this is the solution you are looking for:

```
adb shell pm clear com.your.app
```